# How to represent data to store for key field in google cloud datastore

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a nodejs setup on google datastore and have a `Kind - Event`, where there is a `one-many` relationship for entity `user - Key(User,'id')`

How to store/push data to this entity?
I tried to send the whole user json object with keeping `user` as key, but its not working.

```
Table/Kind - Event
column/property - user which is of type Key(kind,id)
```

I am passing the object of event as

```
{
'property' : 'value',
 How to represent data for key here??   
}


var ds = gcloud.datastore.dataset({projectId: 'pId'});

function create(data, kind, cb) {
    var entity = {
      key: ds.key(kind),
      data: toDatastore(data, ['description'])
    };

    ds.save(
      entity,
      function(err) {
        if(err) { return cb(err); }
        data.id = entity.key.id;
        cb(null, data);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: explain further, your discription makes little sence

Comment: Can you post your code?  How is it not working?